# Discord.js with typescript - post multiple commands

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, discord.js

I have a problem refreshing the slashcommands in typescript. I can only pass an array of one command object as body to the Discord API. Whenever I do more, I am getting a "Invalid Form Body".
The json:

```
[{"name":"ping","description":"Replies with Pong!"},{"name":"userCount","description":"Returns the number of users online."}]
```

Comment: Can you copy paste the entirely of the relevant part of error message? Usually it's at least 1 full line, sometimes several lines.

Comment: name[APPLICATION_COMMAND_INVALID_NAME]: Command name is invalid

Comment: I have commented out the "usercount"- command and wrote another just to test. It seems like "userCount", as well as "countMyUsers" are invalid.

Comment: Just by testing, I guess that all commands have to be in lowecase.

Answer (score 2):

Every command has to be named in lowercase.